# Redactor 10, minimum image size

Tags: redactor

We want to upgrade our app to use redactor 10 but for some reason there seems to be a minimum image size. After embedding an image you can resize it freely, but you cant make it smaller than a certain minimum. This behaviour can be observed on in the demo on their website.

http://imperavi.com/redactor/ (try to make the mountain image very small, at some point it will not go smaller)

Redactor 9 didn't do this and we dont want this behaviour. We have been unable to find a way to either disable this feature (or is it a bug?) or lower the minimum size.

Does anybody know a way to change this or have any other info on this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this in the redactor sourcecode (line 3235 through 3254 in 10.0.5):

```
            moveResize: function(e)
            {
                ...

                if (height < 50 || width < 100) return;

                ...
            },
```

Clearly the values can't be changed or the behaviour disabled without altering the redactor source itself. So we have resorted to modifying this line. It's not pretty but it works. I hope they will make this configurable sometime.